# java class file contains comments - why?

Tags: java

When I open `MyClass.class` file in my Eclipse editor, it shows me comments as well the code.

Shouldn’t the `.class` file be optimized to remove comments? I was expecting to see optimized code sans comments.

I see this when I open String.class in Eclipse.

```html
    /**
     * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
     * <code>String</code> object is computed as
     * <blockquote><pre>
     * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
     * </pre></blockquote>
     * using <code>int</code> arithmetic, where <code>s[i]</code> is the
     * <i>i</i>th character of the string, <code>n</code> is the length of
     * the string, and <code>^</code> indicates exponentiation.
     * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
     *
     * @return  a hash code value for this object.
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
            char val[] = value;

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                h = 31 * h + val[i];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're viewing comments or javadoc?

Comment: Are you sure the comments you see are in the class file?  If the corresponding source is available to Eclipse, then it may be automagically presenting comments to you from there.

Comment: I have updated question above with code snippet. It did not allow me to paste the code here in comments as it was too long. and did not allow to paste screenshot as I don't have enough reps/credit.

Answer (score 4):

When Eclipse opens a `.class` file, it generates a readable representation of the byte codes as well as comments (where it can and where it figures they would be helpful). These comments are not part of the `.class` file. (However, if debugging information is present in the `.class` file, it will make use of that when generating the comments.)

EDIT: Based on your updated question, I'd say that what's happening is that Eclipse is associating a source file with the `.class` file and is showing that instead of the byte codes. For the Java API classes, this is usually because the library definition in Eclipse is set up to point to a source .jar file.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply Ted. I just updated my original question above with code snippet from String.class. Would these descriptive comments and meaningful variable names generated by Eclipse?

Comment: @GenericPerson - Ah. That's different from what I imagined. I've updated my answer.